# Lerna & CRA issue "lerna run --parallel start" does not start the devServer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, lerna

I have 2 projects under lerna packages. One of them is a package and another one is a cra website. When I executed "yarn start" under each package I can see the build folder and respectively the website being loaded in dev server:

1. package 1 >> "start": "tsc",
2. package 2 >> "start": "react-scripts start",

The problem is when I execute "yarn start" from root (lerna root) the execution finishes but the site from the second package does not start.

> > "start": "lerna run --parallel start"

I tried with exec as well, but still nothing.

```
..\vtest\src\client>yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ lerna exec --parallel -- yarn start
lerna notice cli v3.22.0
lerna info Executing command in 2 packages: "yarn start"
webcore: $ tsc
websample: $ react-scripts start
websample: i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.121/
websample: i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
websample: i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from ..\src\client\packages\websample\public
websample: i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
websample: Starting the development server...
lerna success exec Executed command in 2 packages: "yarn start"
Done in 3.27s.
```

Thanks for any info that could help.

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8685

This is a known issue in CRA, I fixed it by changing

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

to

```
"start": "CI=true react-scripts start",
```